# Pause Excel VBA whilst updating external data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is looping. I want to set it going to record dynamic data coming in from an external source.

However, whilst the macro is running it is not allowing the external data to update.

I have tried DoEvents but the data is simply not refreshing from the external source until the macro stops.

Can anyone advise an answer?

Thanks

TT

Comment: You do not need to pause Excel - unless you are planning to write a class with [asynchronous behaviour.](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/05/multi-threaded-vba.html) For faster performance it's better to keep sheet-code traffic to a minimum. :) Or perhaps you could show us some sheet data you are using - explain a little bit more your data flow.

Comment: You could use application.ontime to call your processing event on regular intervals instead of looping indefinitely, but it's hard to give a more specific suggestion without more information.

Comment: Post you code please, that will help.

Answer (score 1):

GOOD QUESTION (no matter what the others said) and no code required to answer it. And the answer is: The problem is with the External connections and not with the code.

Go to the ribbon> Data > Connections. Now for each connection there go to Properties and disable Background refresh.

Background refresh is the option that will make the external data update a paralel instead of serial process. Disabling it will put it back in the serial line and your code will have to wait until the refresh is done!

Good luck.